# ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) solutions not working

Tags: mysql, mariadb

i tired all the solutions given in google in first 10 tabs but nothing worked.
anyone help out

also 
 sudo service mysql start
Job for mariadb.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mariadb.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJ0Rl.png)
gives this output